# Connect Manager Returns "No Release Found for "xxxx" skipping," and does nothing

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, magento-connect, downloader

I have a problem. My site doesn't use ssl for now. When i try to install an extension from magento connect by using magento connect manager it just returning "please wait" screen and after a while its showing No releases for 'Clarion_Customerattribute', skipping  for example.

I tried everything and i get this error about all extension, i tried a lot different extensions.

I tried to delete cache.cfg and connect.cfg from "download" folder.

What you guys can suggest?

[image]

[image]

I also tried installing extension with ssh and setted the permissiıon of mage-setup to 550.
This is the screen i get after these steps.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I just realized my other store is not installing extension also. Another store, another server all different stacks. Is magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ has a problem? Or am i complete idiot to do same mistakes in 2 servers :)

Comment: What happens when you paste the links from Magento Connect in your webbrowser?Could be either they are having issues or your are having a DNS issue.

Comment: Oh i tried that also, browser tried long time to open link and then i got this "504 Gateway Time-out

nginx/0.8.55"

I don't use Zenmate, im using my default dns settings that given by my isp and im connecting from Turkey.

Comment: Now i made a fresh install about 10 minutes ago and it still continues.

Comment: im getting the same issue - im going to assuming its a connect issue for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this problem just navigate to `Settings` and find `Magento Connect Channel Protocol:`

You have to change it from HTTP to `FTP`!

This will resolve your problem.

Tested and working, please if it works for you mark my answer as an answer for your question!

Comment: I've checked in settings, there is no option for FTP, just HTTPS and HTTP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in the second tab (Settings) on the download page?
A lot of extension on connect are listed as beta in stead of "Stable".

If you change the state to "Beta" most extensions will install just fine.

Comment: You are right but i also tried this before. I changed beta, alpha, stable. It didn't worked. Damn.